# How to get useragent in XNA application?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, user-agent

I need to get useragent in my XNA-application to send to the server. I found an example of using JavaScript to get the useragent, but the code did not come, because it works only for silverlight.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solution provide on this URL. I feel it may suits you. Check it out:-

**[Getting the user agent string in an XNA based application](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/63782/391134.aspx)**

### Solution:

For who is interested: I contacted the guy who's responsible for our server and he will make a user agent string, based on info that my application sends to the server. This is the info:

```
OperatingSystem = System.Environment.OSVersion.ToString();

DeviceManufacturer = (string)Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceManufacturer");
DeviceName = (string)Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceName");
```

Comment: No, I do not fit, because useragent phone browser returns a value:
: Mozilla/5.0 compatible MSIE 9.0 Windows Phone OS 7.5 Trident/5.0 IEMobile/9.0 HTC HD7.